# Dynamic page titles in Symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony1, metadata, response, action, title

I'm wondering if anyone's got any good advice/experience regarding setting dynamic meta titles in Symfony?

Currently, the solution I'm aware of would be to use the following code to set a title individidually in each action:

```
$this->getResponse()->setTitle('This is a title');
```

Because I also need translated titles, I could call the i18n helper in the action to get them included in the extracted XLIFFs. No special SEO stuff needed, just a clean title.

However, the above does require that I tweak every single action separately. View.yml is not suitable as I frequently have multiple actions/templates per module.

Is anyone aware of a better approach in Symfony or is this indeed the right/only way to go?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think writing separate titles in every action is OK. But if you want to add some global prefix you can use something like this in layout:

```
<title>SITE NAME — <?= $sf_response->getTitle() ?></title>
```

Also you can probably manipulate a title per module using preExecute() method in actions.

Comment: Using the preExecute method is not a nice way of doing it since it will tie the title logic to the controller. It should really be in the view because it is part of the presentation layer, not the controller.

Answer (score 25):

You should use [slots](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/04#chapter_04_slot_s).

In your layout `<head>` tag:

```
<title><?php echo get_slot('page_title', __('Default page title here')) ?></title>
```

And in an action template:

```
<?php slot('page_title', __('Action page title goes here')) ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

I personally like using the yml files, it separates 'configuration' from code

To deal with dynamic titles I do the follow:

in apps/frontend/config/app.yml

```
all:
  title_separator: ' - '
  title_default: 'TITLE'
```

in apps/frontend/config/view.yml

```
default:
  metas:
    title: %APP_TITLE_DEFAULT%
```

If you need to have data from your actions put into the title, create file lib/myActions.class.php with the following content:

```
<?php

class myActions extends sfActions
{

    protected function setTitle($string)
    {
        $this->getResponse()->setTitle($string . sfConfig::get('app_title_separator') . sfConfig::get('app_title_default'));
    }

}

?>
```

(note: modify this as you like, e.g. put default title at front)

Then change your action.class.php to extend myActions instead of sfActions

```
class memberActions extends myActions
```

and whenever you need to change the title, just call this in your action

```
$this->setTitle('This is how I roll');
```

and you will get the following title (if using the same config as I did above):

```
This is how I roll - TITLE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$i18n = $this->getContext()->getI18N();
$this->getResponse()->setTitle('Your title' . ' | ' . $i18n->__('your module name'));
```